# What runs a g-shock watch?

Tags: pcb, fpga, asic

I am currently trying to learn more about watches and what it takes to build them. I currently own a watch called the G-Shock 7900b and was wondering what runs it inside. Here is a link to the watch:

http://www.gshock.com/watches/Classic/GW7900B-1#

I am wondering if this uses an ASIC or a FPGA? I looked all over the internet but have had no luck finding an answer. Some of the features include receiving radio signals and having preset dates coded into the watch until 2099. Does this mean that this watch has memory? I always assumed that watches did not have a processor or memory.

Any suggests to these questions?

Comment: If they didn't have memory then how would they remember what numerals they're supposed to be displaying?

Comment: That is very true. I assumed that there were maybe little cells that helped remember the states but thats it. What kind of memory would be present in a watch such as this?

Comment: Watches are often run by 4-bit mask-programmed microcontrollers made in special low-voltage low-power CMOS processes. They're not widely shown on the interwebs because the minimum order per code set would be something like 50-100K pieces.

Comment: Those "little cells" count as memory.

Comment: So would there be a processor on a watch like this? Or would that only be necessary for a smart type watch?

Comment: Given the graphics it generates, it almost certainly has a processor of some sort. It's entirely possible that Casio has produced a custom low-power low-speed processor optimized for timepiece use, and uses the same chip in all (or most) of their digital watches.

Comment: If I were to take apart my watch to learn more about the board, is there a way to look at the board and figure out what they did in reference to the processor?

Comment: I think there is a reverse engineering stack exchange, where this question might get better answers. Might have died since I last heard of it, though.

Comment: Watches updated by GPS's will work outside the range of WWVB. Highest precision can be had using CSAC (Chip Scale Atomic Clock) although costly now, should come down in size and price in the future. Google images have several. http://www.ablogtowatch.com/hoptroff-16-atomic-wrist-watch-1000-year-accuracy/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The watch runs either on special ASIC (if volume is very high), or on MCU (microcontroller), often the supercheap version of MCU which is mask programmable and which uses very low clockrate (less than 1MHz)

They do have memory, but often very little of it -- a small MCU might only have 16 bytes of memory (as registers), while ASIC would only have enough memory bits to store current time and any applicable alarms.

Here is a link to a very simple watch ASIC: http://www.integral.by/eng/download/1077/IZ6199TSe.pdf . Note that this chip comes as a bare die, 1.4x1.2mm big. It will be encapsulated in the black epoxy blob on the actual watch PCB.

G-Shock may also run a bigger ASIC or an MCU; it will also be encapsulated in epoxy, but information about it is proprietary and will not be published anywhere.